# Evaluate, NDSolve and ReplaceAll do not work with tables of solutions

Tags: replacement, warning-messages

Why does the following report an error even though it returns a (seemingly valid) result? It's also weird that it returns a list of lists, whereas I would expect just a list.

```
data = {1, 2};
sols = Table[NDSolve[{b'[t] == data[[i]], b[0] == 1.25}, {b}, {t, 0, 15}], {i, 1, 2}];

Table[Evaluate[b[10] /. sol], {sol, sols}]
```

It throws the cryptic error:

> ReplaceAll::reps: {sol} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a
> valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Note: This is a minimal example; please do not suggest moving things significantly around; I wish to maintain a list of solutions and then be able to pick one and choose to evaluate some of its values ad hoc.

Comment: If you remove the `Evaluate` it works. `Table[b[10] /. sol, {sol, sols}]`  I think because you hade `Evaluate` there, it tried to do it on `sol` before the iterator took hold and by then `sol` had not value assigned to it yet.  But after that, it does have a value. That is why your got correct output eventually but there was an error first time, If you want to use `Evaluate` you can try `Table[z = sol; Evaluate[b[10] /. z], {sol, sols}]`

Comment: @Nasser I see. But then I still get a list of lists, which doesn't seem right. I'm not prescribing it to give me a list of lists. I expect just a list of numbers. Could you help with that?

Comment: or you can do `Table[b[10] /. Flatten@sol, {sol, sols}]`   the extra `{}` is due to the original solutions having `{{{...}}}}`

Comment: try also `sols = Table[
  NDSolve[{b'[t] == data[[i]], b[0] == 1.25}, {b}, {t, 0, 15}], {i, 1,
    2}];
Flatten[b[10] /. sols]`